# Need Help changeing size of an image

Tags: html, css, w3c

Here is the two images i want the chance the rapper picture to be the same size as skepta image.

http://prntscr.com/eextsd

and here is a picture of my code

http://prntscr.com/eexvln

Comment: You added blockquote instead of your code.

Comment: hey i'm quite new to posting here could you help me out?

Comment: add parts of your code to question,

Comment: Use the snippet it's an icon that looks like `<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your images are fundamentally different sizes. You can force it but it will stretch the image. It's best to get the same size from the beginning using a photo editing tool.

If you want though, you can add `height` to your code and tweak both `height` and `width` in both images until you see what you want.

like this:

`style="width:60%; height:???"`

Comment: Hey this didn't work <<div class="w3-row w3-padding-32">
      <div class="w3-third">
        <p><b>Chance The Rapper</b></p>
        <img src="chance.png" class="w3-round w3-margin-bottom" alt="Random Name" style="width:60%; height:80%">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-third">
        <p>Skepta</p>
        <img src="skepta.jpg" class="w3-round w3-margin-bottom" alt="Random Name" style="width:60%">
      </div>

Comment: sorry to disturb you but it didn't work i made a typo

Comment: I think the best results would be to edit the image with a photo editor. Otherwise you'll stretch the images out of proportion.

Comment: Great! glad I could help